# How do authorization grants work with federated authentication?

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, auth0, pkce

I struggle to understand how do Authorization grants work with federated authentication.
At the moment i am creating some Social/Enterprise connections on Auth0 and i don't understand at why different Authorization Grants should even matter in this case. If both IdP's are exchanging info, does it matter what Grant should be supported? I've tried to find information online, but i feel like i can't get a decent answer :)

As an example in attachment is

standard Authorization Code Flow with PKCE diagram

[image: 1]

can someone explain where does external IdP's fits into this, and what communicates to what?

At the moment i am creating some Social/Enterprise connections on Auth0 and i don't understand at why different Authorization Grants should even matter in this case. If both IdP's are exchanging info, does it matter what Grant should be supported? I've tried to find information online, but i feel like i can't get a decent answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your setup, this is how the overall flow works:

- Your app runs a code flow using OAuth and OpenID Connect standards - to connect to Auth0. It is your responsibility to code this securely.
- Auth0 runs another code flow to connect to the upstream IDP. You can assume that this is done securely by Auth0.

**CODE FLOW**

Your app needs to first send a front channel request to Auth0, which occurs in the browser:

```
GET http://login.example.com/oauth/authorize
?client_id=my-client
&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/callback
&response_type=code
&scope=openid profile
&code_challenge=WhmRaP18B9z2zkYcIlb4uVcZzjLqcZsaBQJf5akUxsA
&code_challenge_method=S256
&state=CfDJ8Nxa-YhPzjpBilDQz2C...
```

Your app then makes a direct HTTP POST to Auth0 to get tokens:

```
POST http://login.example.com/oauth/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=my-client
&client_secret=U2U9EnSKx31fUnvgGR3coOUszko5MiuCSI2Z_4ogjIiO5-UbBzIBWU6JQQaljEis
&code=I9xL9DY9jAYHPuHSiW2OpWUaNRW4otei
&grant_type=authorization_code
&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/callback
&code_verifier=HlfffYlGy7SIX3pYHOMJfhnO5AhUW1eOIKfjR42ue28
```

**BEST PRACTICES**

The parameters you send are important for your app to be considered secure. A couple of best practices here:

- Use `response_type=code` to keep tokens out of the browser response, so that you receive all tokens in the second message's response
- Use PKCE, as in the link you sent, which proves that the party that sent the first request is also sending the second request

Ensure that whatever libraries you are using in your tech stack, result in messages similar to the above.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and for such a descriptive answer, Gary!